# Energy from gravity

Tags: gravity

Let's say I have a Balloon. In order to float the balloon I need 1 kg of air added to the balloon. If we are moving this air against gravity that's 100j.

The balloon floats 100km into the atmosphere as it is lighter than air. The 1kg balloon now has 100kj of potential energy we gained from applying 100j to float it. This is a 1000:1 return.

Can I get unlimited potential energy simply by floating a balloon?

Comment: Comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post.

Comment: How does adding air to a ballon make it float in air? And 100 km is the Karman line.

Comment: Think about gravity as an energy bank. You can't make a withdrawal unless there has been a deposit.

Comment: Voting to reopen. The questioner is asking a straightforward question, not promoting a personal theory. They have a misunderstanding about how gravitational potential energy works, but we do not close questions just because the questioner has a misunderstanding.

Comment: The answers are unsatisfactory.

Comment: @DhsusU373u3u Please understand this : Contrary to what some [ape video game hero](https://overwatch.fandom.com/wiki/Recall) can tell, science is not about seeing what the world could be or what you want it to be. It's all about trying our very best to understand the world as it is. This implies you need sometimes to throw your idea (read "hypothesis") into the bin when you see past experiences and most other specialists go against your beliefs. I understand it's not comfortable at all , but every scientist had to accept this difficult fact in their life to grow stronger and better.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Stack exchange screwed up badly here.

The real reason is that the balloon makes the air colder because the collisions that cause buoyancy depend on temperature, and when the collisions happen particles stop moving which sets their kinetic energy to zero.

Of course motion is relative so this doesn't actually affect the KE, relativity implies a perpetual motion machine.

This makes a perpetual motion machine possible via maxwell demon type phenomena. Launching balloons in a certain way would destroy the earth.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where the $100\text{ J}$ or $100\text{ kJ}$ values are coming from, but from what I gather the essence of the question is about how a balloon can spontaneously rise, gaining gravitational potential energy "for free". The force responsible of course is the buoyant force, doing work on the balloon.

There are two kinds of potential energy here. One is the familiar gravitational potential energy, usually written as $U_g = mgh$ close to the Earth's surface. Since the buoyant force is conservative, we can also associate a potential energy with it, expressed as
$$U_b =- \rho_fVgh=-\frac{\rho_f}{\rho}mgh.$$
Here, $\rho_f$ is the mass density of the fluid (air) surrounding the balloon, and $\rho$ is the average mass density of the balloon. $U_b$ is in fact just the gravitational potential energy of the surrounding air itself, changing as air gets displaced by the balloon. I'm making several simplifying assumptions here to keep the math simple (like constant $g$ and volume $V$), but the ideas can be generalized.

The total potential energy is
$$U=U_g + U_b=\left(1-\frac{\rho_f}{\rho}\right)mgh.$$

If the balloon is "lighter" than air (meaning $\rho<\rho_f$, which will require a gas different from air), the balloon will rise, losing potential energy in the process.

You could certainly extract work by floating lighter gases up in air (converting potential energy to work, just as you can by [letting heavy things fall down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_battery)), but you can't keep repeating this in a cyclical process because it would take work to bring the gas back down.

Comment: You don't "lose" potential energy by gaining potential energy. The balloon is also doing work so your math fails that way. I can run the balloon to drop something to earth at high speed over and over.

Comment: @DhsusU373u3u I'd suggest you read again. Or enjoy your unlimited free energy I suppose.

Comment: OK I will then. You'll die of peak oil in 6mo

Answer (score 0):

> Can I get unlimited potential energy simply by floating a balloon?

No.   To get unlimited energy from your balloon, you would need unlimited supplies of lighter-than-air substance here at the bottom of the atmosphere.   Such substances take energy to collect and concentrate.   So the energy you got from lifting the balloon's mass is compensated by the energy it took to get the lifting gas into the balloon.

Once the balloon has lifted to it's height, you can't now pull the gas back down to the ground to re-use it, without spending more energy than it gave you.

> I need 1 kg of air added to the balloon. If we are moving this air against gravity that's 100j.

It's not clear what this calculation is intending.   Energy is spent by moving a mass in a gravitational field, or by moving a force across a distance.   There's no distance shown here, so I don't know what the 100J represents.

Comment: I don't see how the material would be an issue.

Comment: Balloons don't float all by themselves.   You have to do something to make them float.   What is that?   Where did the energy to do that come from?

Comment: That seems like a strange objection, there should be some more direct reason.

Comment: @DhsusU373u3u No, this is the reason why you can get *some* energy from this method but not unlimited energy.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I get unlimited potential energy simply by floating a balloon ?

No. You can get some energy from this method, but not an unlimited amount of energy.

To make the balloon rise you have to fill it with some lighter-than-air gas *or* heat the air inside it. If you heat the air inside it then this takes energy and you recover less energy from the rising balloon than you use heating the air. If you fill the balloon with some lighter-than-air gas then supplies of this gas at the surface are limited and eventually you run out, so the available energy is limited by supplies of the gas. You could try to replenish the supplies of lighter-than-air gas by extracting it from the balloon at the top of its journey and taking it back down to the surface - but remember that the gas is buoyant so you have to do work to get it back down to the surface, which uses up the energy that you gained from the balloon on the way up.

Comment: "recover less energy from the rising balloon than you use heating the air"  prove this.

Comment: @DhsusU373u3u Conservation of energy. If, however, you are doubting conservation of energy then there are many simpler ways to build a perpetual motion machine.

Comment: I'm impressed by your lack of math.

Comment: @DhsusU373u3u If you truly want maths, you could start with wikipedia, which contains some formulas. Beware though, that's quite complex (and it's why Gandalf didn't offer you all sorts of maths ^^). Beyond the law of conservation, I suggest you look at [isolated, closed and open systems in thermodynamics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamics#System_models), it's very important to understand the problem we have to keep the same energy in the balloon.